# Битрикс - сортировка новостей по трем полям и последствия копирования компонента

Tags: битрикс

До текущего момента новости сортировались по:

```
"SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
"SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
"SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
"SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC"
```

Но потребовалось изменить сортировку на противоположную (т.е. сначала старые новости). Такой вариант не сработал (новости были вперемешку, у большинства из них дата начальной активности не задана):

```
"SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
"SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
"SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
"SORT_ORDER2" => "DESC"
```

Хотел было попробовать такой вариант, но обнаружил, что в стандартом компоненте `news` возможна сортировка только по двум полям:

```
"SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
"SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
"SORT_BY2" => "CREATED",
"SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
"SORT_BY3" => "SORT",
"SORT_ORDER3" => "DESC"
```

Решил скопировать компоненты `news` и `news.list` из `/bitrix/components/` в `/local/components/custom/`. Затем в файле `/local/components/custom/news/templates/.default/news.php` заменить в `IncludeComponent` `bitrix:news.list` на `custom:news.list`. Т.е. сделать так, чтобы все, кроме списка новостей по-прежнему было завязано на стандартный компонент Новости.

В результате чего съехала верстка на странице списка новостей (кастомный шаблон перестал применяться). Я попробовал поправить - скопировал папки `news` и `news.list` из `/local/templates/папка_темы/components/bitrix/` в `/local/templates/папка_темы/components/custom/`. Не помогло.

Помогите понять, в чем проблема. Все вроде логично и правильно сделал.

На оф.форум обратиться не могу, т.к. являюсь привлеченным со стороны программистом.

UPD: Судя по всему, когда я в файле `/local/components/custom/news/templates/.default/news.php` заменяю в `IncludeComponent` `bitrix:news.list` на `custom:news.list`, он действительно берет `/local/components/custom/news.list` с его шаблоном. А изначально в Битриксе компонент `news` берет шаблон для `news.list` у себя внутри. Как это поправить, не знаю.

UPD2: И при этом, ничего еще и не работает. Такая тривиальная задача как сменить порядок сортировки на противоположный, а столько ада.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

думаю можно решить проблему без такой жесткой кастомизации.

Первый вариант:
создаем пустой компонент (думаю болванку написать вам не составит труда по аналогии с системными компонентами). 
Вставляем шаблон только что созданного компонента в то место, где должен быть news.list c кастомной сортировкой, 
передаем в этот компонент нужные параметры от комплексного (ИД инфоблока и прочее), 
в самом шаблоне создаем файл result_modifier.php и в нем используем [CIBlockElement::getList()](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php). 
Первым параметром метод принимает массив $arOrder, где можно задать любую нужную сортировку по требуемым параметрам

Второй вариант я бы счел более правильным:

Вы уже вынесли компонент news.list в в папку local. Компонент news вам там не нужен совсем.

открываем файл component.php(в вашем кастомном компоненте news.list) и смотрим на вхождения SORT_BY* и SORT_ORDER*
по аналогии дописываем ваше SORT_BY3 и SORT_ORDER3. Внимательно ищите вхождения! первый кусок кода вам попадется ориентировочно с 34 по 43 строчки, а параметры выборки для гетЛиста должны быть на 277-281 строке.

Добавляем наши требуемые параметры и все работает) Не забудьте у вызванного кастомного компонента назначить эти парматеры

Comment: Боюсь, что ваше предложения я не совсем понял. У меня на странице включается bitrix:news, который в свою очередь вроде обращается к bitrix:news.list, в котором уже и идет GetList с полями сортировки. Мне кажется, тут болванка, которая куда-то передает параметры, ничего не сделает. Я не настолько хорошо Битрикс знаю, если честно.

Comment: Правильно. news - комплексный и он передает параметры внутрь компонента в файлы news.php/detail.php и другие. 

Да, в самом news.list используется метод GetList (но ядро то трогать нельзя и собственно логику работы стокового компонента менять нельзя), НО чтобы привести выборку к тому виду, который вам нужен - требуется модификация именно стокового гетлиста из компонента news.list.

Сейчас дополню ответ, еще мысль пришла

Comment: Вот я и попытался так сделать, но шаблон съехал. Т.е. почему-то шаблон из `/local/templates/текущая_тема/components/custom` не работает для пространства компонентов `custom`, которое я же и создал в `/local/components/`

Comment: @user64675 работает, попробуйте в файле где вызываете этот компонент убрать в конце $component - это может мешать

Comment: "Компонент news вам там не нужен совсем." - А тут вы не правы. Потому что если не внести изменения в `news`, то он будет вызывать стандартный Битриксовский `news.list` вместо кастомного. Я же его в отдельное пространство вынес.

Comment: скопируйте код с самими компонентом в кодшару и пришлите сюда, покажу как вызывать кастомные компоненты в стандартных. Код из файла где вызывается нужный вам news.list.

Комплексный компонент будет вызывать то что у него в шаблоне написано и файл самого компонента news никакого отношения не имеет к используемому news.list

Comment: Да нет в файле `component.php` у `news` вызова `news.list`. Есть только в `/bitrix/components/news/templates/.default/news.php` https://pasteio.com/x5rOqSup2Gz7 Строка 56, я там менял на `custom:news.list`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76219/discussion-between-taarim-and-user64675).

Answer (score 0):

Зделайте сортировку по ІD новостей, так как она и будет соответствовать времени создании, и для это не придется ни создавать свой компонент ни модифицировать уже существующий.

```
"SORT_BY1" => "ID",
"SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
"SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
"SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
```

Comment: В свойстве active_from может быть дата отличная от date_create. Так что не совсем этот способ подходит под задачу

Comment: Согласен с Taarim, именно поэтому мне и пришлось кастомизировать.