# Битрикс - после создания кастомного компонента страницы детального просмотра недоступны для гостей

Tags: битрикс

Вот где шло обсуждение о создании кастомного `news` на основе существующего:
[Битрикс - сортировка новостей по трем полям и последствия копирования компонента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815993/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/816003?noredirect=1#comment1296254_816003)

Сегодня обнаружил, что сам список новостей доступен для просмотра гостями, а страницы подробного просмотра нет. Настройки идентичные. В чем проблема и как поправить не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

В моем конкретном случае перекосились правила в файле `urlrewrite.php`. Или кто-то перекосил (людей на проекте несколько).